# How to create a Lead (other object) that will be hidden from ALL reports by default?

Tags: reporting, custom-object

This is a question I raised long time ago on the [ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KOryAAG) site.

I need to create an object (can be either a custom object, or a record type - this time I need it for lead).

The main requirement is that this will be ignored on all reports unless specifically requested.

The story is that we are importing a large number of leads into the system, that will all be under a specific user. These are going to break any report we have about leads.

- I don't want to go over every lead report and add a specific filter (too many users - too many reports) - and that's not the way

How can I achieve that today?

Answer (score 1):

If your Leads are Public Read Only / Public Read Write and it'll take you too long to change the logic - tough luck.

If they're private + Roles / Territories / sharing rules are used:

1. How about importing them with an owner that's outside your regular Role hierarchy? Assign this user no Role at all or create a Role that's not in your main tree (you can have more than 1 1st level node, it just looks weird).
2. If that's not applicable - can you modify your criteria-based sharing rules to say "and some migration flag != 1" for example.

If it'd be a brand new object which you want to prepare upfront and just flip the switch on go-live date I'd say go with checkboxes on the object itself: "allow reports" or "in development / deployed". Obviously it won't work if you have existing data you can't hide.